# Slime to run right CCL

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, dot-emacs, ccl

I have some PC boxes some 32 and some 64 bits. I keep a local svn repo of the CCL implementation on all of them and I have the same `.bashrc` and `.emacs` configurations on all boxes. Therefore when I like to use CCL from within Emacs through Slime I just type by prefixing `M-- M-x slime` and then type `ccl32` and `ccl64` cause I had put something like that in my `.emacs` configuration some time ago.

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
  `((sbcl ("/usr/bin/sbcl" "--noinform" "--no-linedit"))
    (ccl32 ("/path/to/32bit/ccl/lx86cl"))
    (ccl64 ("/path/to/64bit/ccl/lx86cl64"))
    (abcl ("java" "-jar" "/usr/local/share/java/abcl-bin-1.3.3/abcl.jar"))))
```

My question is I just want to put some come conditional in `.emacs` and let it decide which CCL to run on the fly. So I wrote something like this.

```
(defvar *ccl-command*)

(cond ((not (null (string-match ".*64.*" system-configuration)))
   (setq *ccl-command*  "/path/to/64bit/ccl/lx86cl64"))
  ((not (null (string-match ".*86.*" system-configuration)))
   (setq *ccl-command* "/path/to/32bit/ccl/lx86cl")))
```

It pretty much does the trick but it simply doesn't work when I try to put this variable into above `slime-lisp-implementations` like:

```
...
(ccl (*ccl-command*))
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the stupid question. I didn't know Elisp has the backtick like CL too. So

```
(add-to-list 'slime-lisp-implementations `(ccl (,*ccl-command*)))
```

did the trick.